# Grounding an immersion heater

Tags: grounding, heat

I want to ground a bucket/immersion heater:

- should I build a conductive cage around the underwater resistance and connect it to ground?
- would it work to just place the ground wire inside the water, maybe close to the heater?

Comment: A properly installed and properly chosen heater for the purpose likely has grounding built in, but adding a cage around the heater would prevent the bulk of the water being strongly energised in the even the coil shorted to the water.  How much precaution is necessary depends on use.  Is the tank metal and is the tank grounded?  Are there people in it?

Comment: If you look at a modern hot water boiler for example, the element is inside a grounded metal tube, so if the insulation fails it shorts to the tube, hopefully tripping the overcurrent or GFCI protection.

Comment: @KH The tank is plastic and people could put their hand in the water (I'm building a sous vide circulator). So, I want the system to be as safe as possible. So, since I couldn'n find already grounded heaters in my country, I was thinking of grounding them myself. 

I guess one way of increasing safety is to somehow (how?) ground the heater, another one would be to add a circuit breaker on top.

Comment: Why can't you just buy a proper immersion heater element? Please provide a link that explains what *sous vide circulator* is.

Comment: @Andyaka I couldn't find one on amazon/ebay Europe

Comment: Buy a broken device that happens to have one.  Or a new device.  Hot water boilers are cheap.  At any rate, you need both the means of grounding in case of failure and the means to detect that failure and cut the device out.  I'm not sure whether you're allowed to rely on the existing kitchen having ground fault protection, but at the least, a carefully chosen fuse on the line side would be wise.  You could also add a line side cutoff switch when you open the lid.

Comment: You didn't look hard enough. I found at least a dozen on Shamazon (not that I recommend buying anything from them).

Comment: @Andyaka Could you please send a link? I looked really hard on any Amazon (eu) website and also ebay. Maybe I missed something though, I'm quite inexpert.

Sous vide cooking: https://makezine.com/projects/sous-vide-immersion-cooker/

Comment: Google sous vide circulator - that's all I did.

Comment: @Andyaka I want to build them one myelf out of fun, that's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: For this kind of application the safe allowed way is to have the heater *completely encased* in a grounded tube. So whatever it happens the ground will catch current leaks before they can do harm. The most common failure is, of course, that the heater tube corrodes (a pinhole, often), water enters and the RCD trips

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio What happens if the tube has holes? Is safety (greatly) reduces? American bucket heaters present indeed this configuration... (for istance https://www.amazon.com/Precision-Premier-Line-742G-Submersible/dp/B000BDB4UG)

Comment: The "tube" in that link is not part of the heating element. It is a separate guard and is there to prevent the element making direct contact with the tube and burning the food.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safety of immersion water heater](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552989/safety-of-immersion-water-heater)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Random immersion heater image from Amazon.*

Any immersion heater for your application must have a plug with an earth pin. The earth wire must connect the earth pin directly to the element's protective tube.

This method of earthing when used with appropriate circuit breaker and RCD/ELCB/GFCI protects the user from electric shock. It should not be compromised.

If the unit is supplied with a two-pin plug then don't buy it.

Comment: Okay, I finally learned the lesson: **any** heater with a ground plug is already earthed. The only thing to additionally do, is to couple it with a circuit breaker.

Comment: Don't assume that if you're buying junk from Amazon. Test it and open the terminal case to check the connections.

Comment: I think if you have a multi-meter, it is more safe not to open the plug but check if the coil thing is very shorted to the big plug pin.